# How to setup mysql develper for PCF mySQL database to manage it

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I am trying to understand PCF concepts and thinking that once i am done with creating mysql services in PCF, how i can manage that database like creating tables and maintaining that table just like we do in pur traditional environment using mySqldeveoper. I came across one service like PivotalMySQLWeb and tried but didnt liked it much. So if somehow i can get connection details of mysql service , i can use that to connect using sql developer.

Comment: Please check the link, http://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/2-0/use.html or https://github.com/andreasf/cf-mysql-plugin#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links @khalid mentioned are definitely good.

http://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/2-0/use.html
https://github.com/andreasf/cf-mysql-plugin#usage

More generally, you can use an SSH tunnel to access any service, not just MySQL.  This also allows you to use whatever tool you would like to access the service.

This is documented [here](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-9/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html), but if for some reason that goes away here are the steps.

1. Create your target service instance, if you don't have one already.
2. Push an app, any app.  It really doesn't matter, it can be a hello world app.  The app doesn't even need to use the service.  We just need something to connect to.
3. Either Bind the service from #1 to the app in #2 or create a service key using the service from #1.  If you bind to the app, run `cf env <app>` or if you use a service key run `cf service-key MY-DB EXTERNAL-ACCESS-KEY` and either one will give you your service credentials.
4. Run `cf ssh -L 63306:us-cdbr-iron-east-01.p-mysql.net:3306 YOUR-HOST-APP`, where `63306` is the local port you'll connect to on your machine and `us-cdbr-iron-east-01.p-mysql.net:3306` are the host and port from the credentials in step #3.
5. The tunnel is now up, use whatever client you'd like to connect to your service.  For example: `mysql -u b5136e448be920 -h localhost -p -D ad_b2fca6t49704585d -P 63306`, where `b5136e448be920` and `ad_b2fca6t49704585d` are the username and database name from step #3 and 63306 is the local port you picked from step #4.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, if you want to connect aws-rds-mysql (instantiated from Pivotal Cloud Foundry) from IntelliJ, you can use the DB-Navigator Plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) inside IntelliJ, through which, database manipulation can be performed.

After creating the ssh tunnel `$ cf ssh -L 63306:<DB_HOSTNAME>:3306 YOUR-HOST-APP` (as also mentioned in https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html),

- Go to DB Navigator plugin and click on custom under new connection.
- Enter the URL as: jdbc:mysql://:password>@localhost:63306/<database_name>

The following thread might be helpful for you as well [How do I connect to my MySQL service on Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) via MySQL Workbench or CLI or MySQLWeb Database Management App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284031/how-do-i-connect-to-my-mysql-service-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry-pcf-via-mysql-wo/65202309#65202309)